# NSSortDescriptor sorting data in random format

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nssortdescriptor

I have an array of custom objects which I am getting from server.

I want to sort data based on cost. Their is one `totalCost` field in my array which is of type `NSString`.

Now I am using `NSSortDescriptor` like this:

```
  NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptrCost;
        sortDescriptrCost = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"totalCost"
                                                        ascending:YES];

  NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptrCost,nil];
        NSArray *sortedArray = [unchnagedOriginalData sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Now when the cost is more than `100` then it is sorting well. But when the data contains `cost` `less than 100` the sorting breaks.Here is the output:

This is the sorted order I am getting:

```
113--totalCost
113--totalCost
120--totalCost
149--totalCost
182--totalCost
255--totalCost
259--totalCost
263--totalCost
263--totalCost
67--totalCost
80--totalCost
```

Comment: since it's a string, it will be sorted by ascii value rather than numerical value.

Comment: Don't sort strings as if they were numbers. "8" > "6" > "1", which is why 67 sorts after the others, and 80 after that.

Comment: your totalcost seems like its a string.. so try this out.   Change your key value to "totalCost.intValue" or "totalCost.integerValue"

Comment: @Avi got that.. is their any way to covert it in int while sorting...or I have to go with comparator

Comment: @RahulMishra yeah, use a comparator

Comment: @RajTandel Thanks it just work great :)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    if ([a valueForKey:@"totalCost"] &&  [b valueForKey:@"totalCost"])     {
       // Compare object values and return as per your expectations 
    }
}];
```

This may help you for sure